# Phasor length of current and Voltage in AC

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, potential

$V=IR$ (for voltage and Current Amplitudes) in AC and in AC circuit with just a resitor when you draw phasor, should the length of I phasor be always less than $V$? I have seen some phasor diagrams with $I$ longer than $V$. How can I explain this?

Answer (score 1):

$V$ and $I$ are different quantities so what you see on a phasor diagram is the **phase relationship between $V$ and $I$** with one phasor being scaled in volts, eg 1 cm is equivalent to 1 volt, and the other phasor being scaled in amps, eg 1 cm = 0.2 amps.

In terms of length on a phasor diagram you can only compare like with like eg length of phasor corresponding to the voltage across a capacitor to the length of the phasor corresponding to the voltage across a resistor.

Here is a phasor diagram which I have picked at "random" where the length of the current phasor does not mean much with its direction giving a reference when comparing its phase with the phase of the voltages.

[image]